# How to change the "points" in my graph to become a "bar/histogram bar" in a PRCC plot

Tags: r, correlation

I have a question regarding LHS/PRCC in R. I need to change the "points" in my graph to become a "bar/histogram bar" (see the photo). I have solved the LHS/PRCC and plot the values but I require a bar plot of the coefficients. Below is my code. [image][image]

Below is my code:

```
plot(summary$original, main='Partial rank correlation coefficients', ylim=c(-1,1),
     xlab='', ylab='Coefficient',
     axes=FALSE)
axis(2)
axis(1, at=seq(1:8), labels=c("A",expression(lambda[d]),expression(sigma[d]),expression(m[d]),expression(k[d]),expression(mu[d]),'c',expression(beta[d])), las=1)
mtext(text='Parameter', side=1, line=2.5)
box()
#for(i in 1:8) lines(c(i,i),c(summary[i,4], summary[i,5])) #the lines for CI
abline(h=0)
```

Comment: use `barplot`. Chek its arguments by `?barplot`.

Comment: Hi,it is actually almost correct. But the axis labels are now not aligned with the barplot.

Comment: use `names.arg` in `barplot` insted of `axis` to define labels

Comment: thanks! now it is correct